# Why doesn't Rails respond with error 406?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller has the following action:

```rb
def foo
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv { "foo,bar,baz" }
  end
end
```

But if I visit the corresponding address with the browser, instead of getting a 406 error, I get a 500 error and, in development, `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

I can get a 406 error manually:

```rb
format.all { head :not_acceptable }
```

Shouldn't Rails do that automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually, Rails was correctly sending an HTTP 406, but we mistook it for 500 for two reasons:

- in the `development` environment, we get a 406 **and** the Rails error page, which we thought was only shown when an exception goes unrescued
- in the `production` environment, the exception was logged in Rollbar, presumably before being rethrown and rescued by Rails to send a 406

Using `telnet` or `openssl s_client` confirmed we get a 406 in both cases, though.

The solution in our case was to ignore `ActionController::UnknownFormat` in the Rollbar config:

```
config.exception_level_filters.merge!({
  'ActionController::UnknownFormat' => 'ignore'
})
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data "foo,bar,baz" }
end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Add some explanation; explain why does this code work?

Comment: Also, this was the code I had originally but this produces an error because the template is missing for HTML.